# Как использовать аргументы командной строки в PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Где их прописать я знаю, но как их использовать или вызвать в самой программе?

Answer (score 1):

Через массив `sys.argv`. Например:

```
if len( sys.argv ) != 2:
    print "invalid arguments"
    exit ( 1 )

firstArg = sys.argv[ 1 ]
```

Можно также воспользоваться например библиотекой [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/), пример с оффсайта:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

Здесь из коробки всякие плюшки, типа открытия файла, проверок путей и т.д.

Comment: если я в PyCharm ввожу sys.argv, то среда жалуется на ошибку в этой строке. import sys тоже не могу сделать, среда не позволяет.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕфименко Да, разумеется надо импортировать модуль `sys`. Только что значит, среда не позволяет?

Comment: Когда я прописываю import sys , среда не принимает её, она серого цвета , посивно реагирует на эту строку

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, серым цветом pycharm подсвечивает не используемые импорты, т.е. если вы пишете `import sys`, и далее не используете нигде `sys`, то получите выделение серым цветом.